# Can't run logstash on windows

Tags: cygwin, logstash

I'm currently trying to install and run Logstash on Windows 7 using the guidelines of the [Logstash website](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/tutorials/getting-started-with-logstash).

My first try was with the version 1.4.2, but I got the error:

> Error: Unable to access jarfile /cygdrive/c/Users/hschoonjans/My Documents/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/jar/jruby-complete-1.7.11.jar

Then I tried with a more recent version (1.5.0.rc2), but had a different error message:

> LoadError: no such file to load -- logstash/environment
>     require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1071
>     require at C:/Users/hschoonjans/My Documents/Elasticsearch cluster/logstash-1.5.0.rc2/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135
>      (root) at C:\Users\hschoonjans\My Documents\Elasticsearch cluster\logstash-1.5.0.rc2\lib\logstash\runner.rb:7

For both versions, I only tried the same command in my Cygwin in the logstash directory:

```
bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'
```

This is confusing, in the tutorials there is no allusion to the need of making more configuration.

EDIT: it seems that the problem may occur mainly when using Cygwin. It may be [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634211/unable-to-access-jarfile-under-cygwin) with this issue.

Comment: What about trying a really recent version? Java 5 is 5 years old! Try Java 8.

Comment: You're in for a treat on Windows.  I'm using the Logstash book by James Turnbull, and he recommends using a config file.  However, that turns up a _different_ error during run.  I've just given up and am running it on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, I:

1. Changed the working directory to the bin directory
2. Used the configurations from a .conf file

The command I used:

```
logstash agent -f myconf.conf
```

Answer (score 3):

On `logstash 2.2.2`, there are two different files named `logstash` in the bin directory. I needed to explicitly call the bat file:

```
bin\logstash.bat -f conf_file_name.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, to solve the problem, I added the jruby path to windows PATH environment variable.

It works fine with the jruby included in the logstash package.